# Recursion on a moving window

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I need to apply some computations to a moving window of $N$ items in a time series and I am struggling with doing recursion and shifting the considered window.

To illustrate, please consider the simple function below.

```
myFunction[state_] := Append[state[[2 ;;]], RandomInteger[10]]
initialState = {1, 2, 3};
RandomInteger[10];
state1 = myFunction[initialState]
state2 = myFunction[state1]
```

In reality I am doing some time series analysis.

I am predicting the `t4` based on `t1`, `t2` and `t3`. Then I want to predict `t5` based on `t2`, `t3` and my predicted `t4` and so on.

So after 3 iterations, I will be predicting based on my 3 first predictions

Comment: Is R.M's answer what you want?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you truly are, after 30 min I realize it does not after 10 iterations for me in what I do :-(

Comment: @Mr Wizard, I guess Append[] is a bad example since it is part of the recursion I want to do ?

Comment: Somehow I didn't think that is what you wanted, but I don't yet know what you *do* want.  Please try to provide a more representative example.  Actual manually-generated output would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, i can`t think of a clearer explanation sadly. I am doing a bunch of transformation of values at t1 and t2 to predict t3 then I want to do the same bunch of computations but this time on t2 and t3.... i am sorry if it is not clear :-(

Comment: @500 Could you explain how my answer doesn't do what you've described? I've edited my answer to make the steps clearer, but it still is the same approach...

Comment: @R.M. Ok I am sorry, Now it is worth and I really don`t get the ~ ~ things, I will try to be more clear and come back thank you for your time and attention. This really makes it more obscure to me : state ~Join~ {predict[state[[-n ;;]]]. My function takes a list of 2  (initial state) as argument and return one element : t3. I then want the 2 input to be t2 and predicted t3 to predict t4.

Comment: @500 In the end, after `n` steps do you need the entire list of elements from t1 to tn or just the last two elements? The `~Join~` is basically your Append part... so `{1,2} ~Join~ {3}` will give you `{1,2,3}`. The `predict` function is your function that transforms t1 and t2 into t3

Comment: @R.M, The problem i stat you assume the append thing is in my function whereas my function does not. I thought it was a reap and sow that I could not make work. And the worth is I can`t share my functions :-(. Oh I just understood your question, I need only the last two.

Comment: @R.M. What I need is a sliding window, at first the initial state then its own previous prediction. The window can have a size from 2 to 5 roughly. Many Thanks for you attention, this is driving me insane :-(

Comment: @500 Such a window is built in to the solution— it just isn't explicit like in an imperative style programming. If you change `n` in my code, it'll change your window length. Why don't you create a test example, write the output by hand and then show what output you get with my answer.

Comment: @R.M. Please see what I added to my question I hope it helps to clarify

Comment: @R.M, I think I got it using the second one you posted. I just have very very weird / interesting result it seems... I will keep you posted. Many thanks for your help !

Comment: @500 Seeing your image it's clear why the `NestList` didn't work for you — It's because you've defined your `myFunction` here as _appending_ the new result to the previous two (i.e., returning a list of length 3), whereas you've defined `maFonction` in your file as returning only the updated value (i.e., a list of length 1)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you need to implement some form of a linear predictor and step forward in time starting with an initial state. The solution is still the same as my previous version — i.e., using `Nest`, but it's now written in a clearer form:

```
predict[samples_] := Total[samples] (* Replace Total with your function *) 
step[state_, n_: 2] := state ~Join~ {predict[state[[-n ;;]]]}
Nest[step[#, 3] &, initialState, 10] (* enter your lag (here 3), initialState, iterations *)
```

An example to generate the Fibonacci series with the above:

```
Nest[step, {0, 1, 1}, 10]
(* {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144} *)
```

---

#### Original answer:

You can do it easily with `NestList`:

```
NestList[myFunction, initialState, 5]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking R.M's lead and using the Fibonacci sequence, maybe this example is helpful?

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {b, a + b};

NestList[f, {1, 1}, 7]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {5, 8}, {8, 13}, {13, 21}, {21, 34}}
> ```

Or as an anonymous function:

```
NestList[{#2, # + #2} & @@ # &, {1, 1}, 7]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my first `NestList` answer that you said was not what 500 wanted?

Comment: @R.M I'm trying... (already voted for yours)