# Generating an autoregressive time series

Tags: time-series, random

Find $X_t = c_1 X_{t-1} + \dots + c_n X_{t-n} + n_t$ for given $c_i$, initial conditions $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, and distribution for i.i.d. $n_t$.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient or elegant way to code this than using a for loop.

Comment: I think something like [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5155/5) is what you want. This is the same (or nearly the same) as that question, but yours is much clearer. I guess I'll hold off on voting to close...

Comment: All the answers were good. I learned something from you all; I'm glad I asked. Yes, I meant "generate" when I said "find".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generating an autoregressive time series is not the same as "finding" it, since you have the parameters. If I understand you correctly, this is an application made for `FoldList`:

Here is a simple AR(1) process to illustrate the technique:

```
FoldList[c1 #1 + #2&, x0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],{100}]
```

For example

```
 FoldList[0.9 #1 + #2 &, 0.2, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]]
 ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: A simulated AR(1) process]

For an AR($p$) process with $p>1$, something like this would work:

```
FoldList[Join[{params.#1+#2},Most[#1]]&, startingvalues, 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]]
```

Where `params` is your list of `c` parameters and `startingvalues` is your list of starting values.

Multivariate processes (i.e. simulation of data from a VAR to get a vector of length $p$ at each time period) can be handled similarly except of course that `params` will be a matrix and you'll be saving a matrix consisting of the vector of data for the current period, plus the $p$ lags, at each step. Then you need to extract the matrix of data from the repetitions representing the lags at each step using `Part`, i.e.

```
FoldList[Join[{matrixofparams.#1+#2},Most[#1]]&, matrixofstartingvalues, 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100,p}]][[All, 1, All ]]
```

Comment: Do you think "finding" means something else or that he just expressed himself wrong? If it means something else, what would it be?

Comment: I would have assumed "finding" meant "estimating the parameters", but he has the parameters and the title says "generating", so I interpret him as meaning "simulate". I use the `FoldList` approach to generating an AR process all the time, to show people how functional programming in Mathematica works, and to generate fake economic-looking data for my test graphs.

Comment: Yeah, it's a practical one-liner, +1

Answer (score 7):

I like @RM 's approach. Another one, with a more "mathematical" notation (but I must say I'm not certain of the random behaviour of the way I'm getting the numbers) could be the following

First we create the discrete noise

```
i : noise["Seed"] := i = RandomInteger[{-# , #}] &[Developer`$MaxMachineInteger];
noise[n_Integer] := 
 BlockRandom[SeedRandom[# + n]; 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]] &[noise["Seed"]]
```

Now, `noise` is a realisation of the process. You can realise another one by resetting the seed with `noise["Seed"]=.;`

If you do `DiscretePlot[noise[n], {n, 0, 10}]` several times, you'll see what I mean.

Now, just use `RecurrenceTable`

```
RecurrenceTable[{
    x[0] == 0.5, 
    x[1] == 0.54, 
    x[2] == -2.3,
    x[n] == noise[n] + 0.75 x[n - 1] - 0.23 x[n - 2] + 0.2 x[n - 3]}, 
        x[n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 5):

A straightforward way would be using recursion and memoization. An example:

```
n = 5;
c = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], n]/100;

Clear[x]
Array[(x[#] = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[]]) &, n]; (* Initial conditions *)
x[t_Integer] /; t > n := x[t] = c.Table[x[i], {i, t - 1, t - n, -1}] +
     RandomReal[NormalDistribution[]]

ListLinePlot[x /@ Range[300]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a part with `c.Table`? What it does?

Comment: @zygimantus it's a dot product https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html

Answer (score 5):

Since Version 9 you can also use the built-in functions [RandomFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomFunction.html) and [ARProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ARProcess.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example, to generate data following an AR(1) process with parameter `.3` you can use

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomFunction[ARProcess[{.3}, 1], {1, 100}];
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which, except for the initial observation, is identical to the data generated using  Verbeia's approach:

```
SeedRandom[1]
FoldList[0.3 #1 + #2 &, 0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]];
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Two AR(2) processes:

```
ar2p1 = RandomFunction[ARProcess[{0.9, -.3}, .1], {1, 50}];
ar2p2 = RandomFunction[ARProcess[{-0.9, -.3}, .1], {1, 50}];

ListLinePlot[{ar2p1, ar2p2}, Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> {"ar2p1", "ar2p2"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]